# MYSQL GROUP BY HAVING clause unsing MIN and MAX for a range

Tags: mysql, having-clause

The query:

```
SELECT product_cd, SUM(avail_balance) prod_balance
FROM account
WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY product_cd
HAVING MIN(avail_balance) >= 1000
AND MAX(avail_balance) <= 10000;
```

The table:

```
+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+--------------------+--------+----------------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
| account_id | product_cd | cust_id | open_date  | close_date | last_activity_date | status | open_branch_id | open_emp_id | avail_balance | pending_balance |
+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+--------------------+--------+----------------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
|          1 | CHK        |       1 | 2000-01-15 | NULL       | 2005-01-04         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |       1057.75 |         1057.75 |
|          2 | SAV        |       1 | 2000-01-15 | NULL       | 2004-12-19         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |        500.00 |          500.00 |
|          3 | CD         |       1 | 2004-06-30 | NULL       | 2004-06-30         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |       3000.00 |         3000.00 |
|          4 | CHK        |       2 | 2001-03-12 | NULL       | 2004-12-27         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |       2258.02 |         2258.02 |
|          5 | SAV        |       2 | 2001-03-12 | NULL       | 2004-12-11         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |        200.00 |          200.00 |
|          7 | CHK        |       3 | 2002-11-23 | NULL       | 2004-11-30         | ACTIVE |              3 |          13 |       1057.75 |         1057.75 |
|          8 | MM         |       3 | 2002-12-15 | NULL       | 2004-12-05         | ACTIVE |              3 |          13 |       2212.50 |         2212.50 |
|         10 | CHK        |       4 | 2003-09-12 | NULL       | 2005-01-03         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |        534.12 |          534.12 |
|         11 | SAV        |       4 | 2000-01-15 | NULL       | 2004-10-24         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |        767.77 |          767.77 |
|         12 | MM         |       4 | 2004-09-30 | NULL       | 2004-11-11         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |       5487.09 |         5487.09 |
|         13 | CHK        |       5 | 2004-01-27 | NULL       | 2005-01-05         | ACTIVE |              4 |          16 |       2237.97 |         2897.97 |
|         14 | CHK        |       6 | 2002-08-24 | NULL       | 2004-11-29         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |        122.37 |          122.37 |
|         15 | CD         |       6 | 2004-12-28 | NULL       | 2004-12-28         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |      10000.00 |        10000.00 |
|         17 | CD         |       7 | 2004-01-12 | NULL       | 2004-01-12         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |       5000.00 |         5000.00 |
|         18 | CHK        |       8 | 2001-05-23 | NULL       | 2005-01-03         | ACTIVE |              4 |          16 |       3487.19 |         3487.19 |
|         19 | SAV        |       8 | 2001-05-23 | NULL       | 2004-10-12         | ACTIVE |              4 |          16 |        387.99 |          387.99 |
|         21 | CHK        |       9 | 2003-07-30 | NULL       | 2004-12-15         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |        125.67 |          125.67 |
|         22 | MM         |       9 | 2004-10-28 | NULL       | 2004-10-28         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |       9345.55 |         9845.55 |
|         23 | CD         |       9 | 2004-06-30 | NULL       | 2004-06-30         | ACTIVE |              1 |           1 |       1500.00 |         1500.00 |
|         24 | CHK        |      10 | 2002-09-30 | NULL       | 2004-12-15         | ACTIVE |              4 |          16 |      23575.12 |        23575.12 |
|         25 | BUS        |      10 | 2002-10-01 | NULL       | 2004-08-28         | ACTIVE |              4 |          16 |          0.00 |            0.00 |
|         27 | BUS        |      11 | 2004-03-22 | NULL       | 2004-11-14         | ACTIVE |              2 |          10 |       9345.55 |         9345.55 |
|         28 | CHK        |      12 | 2003-07-30 | NULL       | 2004-12-15         | ACTIVE |              4 |          16 |      38552.05 |        38552.05 |
|         29 | SBL        |      13 | 2004-02-22 | NULL       | 2004-12-17         | ACTIVE |              3 |          13 |      50000.00 |        50000.00 |
+------------+------------+---------+------------+------------+--------------------+--------+----------------+-------------+---------------+-----------------+
```

Result:

```
+------------+--------------+
| product_cd | prod_balance |
+------------+--------------+
| CD         |     19500.00 |
| MM         |     17045.14 |
+------------+--------------+
```

My understanding goes as far as this, from the query above:

```
SELECT product_cd, SUM(avail_balance) prod_balance
FROM account
WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY product_cd
```

Which results in:

```
+------------+--------------+
| product_cd | prod_balance |
+------------+--------------+
| BUS        |      9345.55 |
| CD         |     19500.00 |
| CHK        |     73008.01 |
| MM         |     17045.14 |
| SAV        |      1855.76 |
| SBL        |     50000.00 |
+------------+--------------+
```

My confusion is with:

```
HAVING MIN(avail_balance) >= 1000
AND MAX(avail_balance) <= 10000;
```

Which I interpret as: "Include only the ones having a balance that is greater than or equal to 1,000 and lesser than or equal to 10,000" which would result in

`BUS: 9345.55`

`SAV: 1855.76`

Which is completely wrong when I ran the query as above. Any explanations as to what is going on would help.

Comment: your grouping is incorrect. since you're grouping by `product_cd`, you're going to get the max/min values for ALL of the records in each grouping, no matter which user actually has them. plus, `having` is applied basically at the very last stage of query processing, just before data is fired off to the user. That means the filter is applied AFTER all of the sum/where stuff has been finalized, which also means that any values the `having` would normally exclude will already be included in any aggregate results, such as `sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of MIN(avail_balance) and MIN(avail_balance), try

```
HAVING MIN(SUM(avail_balance)) >=1000 
and MAX(SUM(avail_balance)) <=10000
```

You are getting CD and MM in the result beacause all of their values are in between 1000 to 10000

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the total or the minimum or maximum avail_balance match a certain range? They are different things.

The product CD for instance has a total of 19500, a minimum of 1500 and a maximum of 10000. You are showing the total (`SUM`), but want to see results where the product's minimum (`MIN`) is >= 1000 and the product's maximum (`MAX`) is <= 10000. This is true for CD.

So your query shows the correct results.

Maybe you want these, or maybe you want

```
SELECT 
  product_cd, 
  SUM(avail_balance) AS prod_balance
FROM account
WHERE status = 'ACTIVE'
GROUP BY product_cd
HAVING SUM(avail_balance) >= 1000
AND SUM(avail_balance) <= 10000;
```

instead.